# Input in a For Loop

Tags: c

IF "for loop" is like this,

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
}
```

Then, 
Input can be given either as,

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Hitting Enter Every time for the next Input.

OR

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

With space character between different input values.

Now, How does this thing work?
I mean if loop is running,
then how does it recognizes that Input is given for the next loop cycle wihtout hitting the Enter key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How does this thing work?**

This works because `scanf()` reads only till a `space` or `newline` or `tab` is encountered.

So, when you give input `1 2 3 4 5`, at the first iteration `scanf()` reads `1` and a `space` is encountered and `scanf()` terminates keeping the value `1` to a[0]`. At the next iteration`2` is read the same way.

Answer (score 0):

[The `scanf` (and family) function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with the `"%d"` format reads *white-space delimited* input. If the white-space is a newline or a single space doesn't matter.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> key simply tells the input stream system that input is ready (`stdin` which is used by `scanf` is *line buffered* by default), exactly what that input is doesn't matter.